# PhoneRTC on iOS : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, phonertc

I am building this on Xcode when I build it on Xcode it shows 'Build Successful' But when I type "cordova build ios " I get the above errors shown in image above. I then tried "sudo cordova build ios" but it did not help. I have reinstalled and rebuilt but issue remains same.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add `i386` as valid architecture list as shown in the image below

[image]